Issues Connecting to Redis Service in self-hosted GitHub Actions runner
I'm trying to set up a GitHub Actions workflow to run my unit tests, which include a Redis service container. I've followed all the steps in the documentation here, but I'm encountering an error.
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redistester:6380. Name or service not known.

Here’s the relevant part of my workflow configuration:
name: Start Unit Tests
run-name: Testing ${{ github.ref }} for ${{ github.actor }}
on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  pytest:
    timeout-minutes: 30
    runs-on: self-hosted

    # Service containers to run with `runner-job`
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      redistester:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: redis:7.2.1-alpine
        # Set health checks to wait until redis has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "redis-cli ping"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          # Maps port 6380 on service container to the host
          - 6380:6379

    steps:
      - name: Run unit tests
        run: python3.12 manage.py test tests.sockets --debug-mode --noinput
        env:
          REDIS_HOST: redistester
          REDIS_PORT: 6380

Are there any additional configurations needed for the Redis service to be accessible during the test run?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
A production instance is also running on the same machine which require me to change the port. So I need to make sure the workflow is not killing the production redis server on exit.
Also, all unittests succeed locally. Just not in the runner, they fail at the tests which require a redis connection.
docker ps -a >
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS                                                                 
                                                                       NAMES
fb76367e1d52   redis:7.2.1-alpine                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds (healthy)    0.0.0.0:6380->6379/tcp, :::6380->6379/tcp                             
                                                                       13e28f6bf7644a87aa7931ccf2667369_redis721alpine_e6c6aa

docker inspect redistester >
[
    {
        "Id": "1020f56e2aaf0233d175161e60e8764fc360b500e7330e05def138eb8f559b26",
        "Created": "2024-09-28T13:59:26.468881511Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "redis-server"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2272744,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2024-09-28T13:59:29.887301941Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "starting",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": []
            }
        },
        "Image": "sha256:5f1b29ca6c7aadd4a446df1328127f43ff5dea0c10ea563d440e3029f8538bb1",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1020f56e2aaf0233d175161e60e8764fc360b500e7330e05def138eb8f559b26/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1020f56e2aaf0233d175161e60e8764fc360b500e7330e05def138eb8f559b26/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1020f56e2aaf0233d175161e60e8764fc360b500e7330e05def138eb8f559b26/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1020f56e2aaf0233d175161e60e8764fc360b500e7330e05def138eb8f559b26/1020f56e2aaf0233d175161e60e8764fc360b500e7330e05def138eb8f559b26-json.log",
        "Name": "/360ee5fe74334dda8574db1fe82de854_redis721alpine_e3c551",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "github_network_721061600c374a20aed55109e96c8d41",
            "PortBindings": {
                "6379/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "6380"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": [],
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware",
                "/sys/devices/virtual/powercap"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a1c4b0b7e873483fc22e9c5bb3278dbc9eea38bf40795de8bb996d25992393e-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9ce74a2ade0669fd26837c98717ef8c05f70c9a5531408fef2fff4f2491943d0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/277bb56829ea81e36c81a4f68e0a14f134fb0d3aefa84df87825b24be1c4ff47/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c9fa624c4b22efb424d066adacbbd68d371e3b7d067f78c30d53675261fc7a9a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c12460f04520314ac69a3b77bdf173afad53a593a558a03ae2129f0b406d4742/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b0e757f06406a2f830f4a4f2e3e13c50c9ebb72f61597bd032fd8bf006850b4c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6618267aac57169a41a13fb72cc936d5608f47df6cffd1ab5c73c812b486010/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ad136b5f132d2dd080733a5ae2c904547cb273bfe7673a308bd159cbe1ee88c6/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a1c4b0b7e873483fc22e9c5bb3278dbc9eea38bf40795de8bb996d25992393e/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a1c4b0b7e873483fc22e9c5bb3278dbc9eea38bf40795de8bb996d25992393e/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a1c4b0b7e873483fc22e9c5bb3278dbc9eea38bf40795de8bb996d25992393e/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "ccde95560ed84e61b1e2856fd69367684408f4e2cebbd6374b26b3aa6be41bae",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/ccde95560ed84e61b1e2856fd69367684408f4e2cebbd6374b26b3aa6be41bae/_data",
                "Destination": "/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "1020f56e2aaf",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "6379/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "GITHUB_ACTIONS=true",
                "CI=true",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "REDIS_VERSION=7.2.1",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-7.2.1.tar.gz",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA=5c76d990a1b1c5f949bcd1eed90d0c8a4f70369bdbdcb40288c561ddf88967a4"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "redis-server"
            ],
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "redis-cli ping"
                ],
                "Interval": 10000000000,
                "Timeout": 5000000000,
                "Retries": 5
            },
            "Image": "redis:7.2.1-alpine",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "3a8879": ""
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "c0b3d560b6831dc8da527eb06102362b47785e13435903b2da5637cdcc9b4743",
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c0b3d560b683",
            "Ports": {
                "6379/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "6380"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "6380"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "github_network_721061600c374a20aed55109e96c8d41": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "redistester",
                        "1020f56e2aaf"
                    ],
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                    "NetworkID": "2365ceadcc62dc2b66d10d976bece8c71e7ccae940d698196c4227209c7ff2fd",
                    "EndpointID": "4bf298402bf039e8b7dc9cce8cfc78019409a29fcee03db5768c0cf6abe80527",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.27.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "DNSNames": [
                        "360ee5fe74334dda8574db1fe82de854_redis721alpine_e3c551",
                        "redistester",
                        "1020f56e2aaf"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

docker-compose file for github-action-runner: gist.github.com/0x78f1935/44a61b40b28da1f92a935501c64acd55
My dockerfile looks something like this: gist.github.com/0x78f1935/54dd213af07c584b54b653f07cc78e00

The next section in the linked docs i.e. Configuring the steps for the runner job mentions that the hostname to be used may be localhost or 127.0.0.1. Configure REDIS_HOST accordingly and that should fix it.

I've also tried localhost, changing hostname of the container, forcing to run on bridge, but all with pretty much the same result. Docker inspect shows the container is connected to the required virtual networks.

Are you able to use redis-cli with this service container e.g. redis-cli -h localhost -p 6380 PING? You may have to install the CLI i.e. sudo apt install -y redis-tools.

Just tested on ubuntu-latest with redis-cli and it's working. See workflow and its run.

That is interesting, I'm running on self-hosted docker runner. I do ping and I get a pong back. But this happens within the health check of the service. Not as a step. ubuntu-latest is something I would like to avoid, and I would like to stick with my self hosted environment. See here my runner docker-compose file: https://gist.github.com/0x78f1935/44a61b40b28da1f92a935501c64acd55

Can you provide a public repo including a sample workflow configured with your self-hosted runner?

With the provided docker-compose file in my previous comment, I pretty much build from source the latest released version: https://github.com/actions/runner/releases
My dockerfile looks something like this: https://gist.github.com/0x78f1935/54dd213af07c584b54b653f07cc78e00

You are trying to interact with HOST: redistester while this is just a label, the host is localhost.
You can see it also in your unit test.
Try to add checkout step before tests:
steps:       
# Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests       
  - name: Check out repository code         
    uses: actions/checkout@v4 

Edit — Running inside container on self-hosted:
Ref are from ValKey-Glide CI/CD I made, Its OSS so you can also jump and see for yourself.
Since you are running in the same env your prod is running, you are limiting yourself from using same configurations like port, container name etc.
What you can utilize in order to avoid is:
jobs:
  pytest:
    timeout-minutes: 30
    runs-on: self-hosted
    container: # this is the important part
        image: Image you want to run the job in -> Your Debian
    services:
        redis:
            image: redis:7.2.1-alpine 
        # and so on ...


The result is that you start your run inside a Debian image on your self-hosted, so the env is completely clean and doesn't interfere with the host env.
From there you can keep working as you would exactly do in your prod env, naming, ports, software, everything.
And since you run inside a container, you can use the exact same config the guide say without trying to debug their implementations and adjust it to make it run with your Redis in piece.
In our release, I have a complex matrix of options which our build need to build-release on them all (and this just one language out of 4).
One of the supported platform is node:alpine docker on aarch64.
So I run the job on self-hosted, inside node:alpine image and just then the workflow start.
Also using ValKey/Redis-OSS, but not with services, running it within the workflow. But you can do with, use all they give you.
BTW — if it works, you replace the client you use with ValKey-Glide.
Solution
According to the docs, services tag only works for ubuntu-latest github-hosted runner.
Instead of using services, try to install redis in your steps instead so its available for your self-hosted runner.
To install redis:
    steps:
      - name: Install Redis
        run: |
          apt install lsb-release curl gpg -y
          # Remove the existing key file if it exists
          rm -f /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg
          # Fetch and dearmor the GPG key
          curl -fsSL https://packages.redis.io/gpg | gpg --batch --no-tty --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg
          chmod 644 /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg
          echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list
          apt update -y
          apt install redis -y
          # Start Redis on port 6380
          redis-server --port 6380 --daemonize yes

(optional) To wait for redis
      - name: Wait for Redis to be ready
        run: |
          for i in {1..10}; do
            if redis-cli -p 6380 ping | grep -q PONG; then
              echo "Redis is ready!"
              break
            fi
            echo "Waiting for Redis..."
            sleep 1
          done
          if ! redis-cli -p 6380 ping | grep -q PONG; then
            echo "Redis did not start in time" >&2
            exit 1
          fi

Connecting to 127.0.0.1:6380 should work now

When I try localhost I pretty much get the same result.

[Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6380), [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address connecting to localhost:6380. I've included a docker inspect in the original post.

What OS is your self-hosted?

Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) Good thinking, but it's not becausee I'm running the runner on windows

Try to add checkout step before tests:
      # Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4 

Adding it to answer so md is more clear.

The checkout step is the first step in this workflow already. Before the unittests run, the following things happen: Checkout, Install of dependencies, Database prep, Some additional artifact steps and then the tests happen. All in the same file. I just didnt post it because I felt it's unrelated.
In addition, it might be worth mentioning that the whole flow worked before, until I introcuded some tests with a required redis service.

Can you share test code?

I'm unwilling to share the tests themselfs. But when I run a local redis service and run my tests locally everything works fine. I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with how the github-action-runner is spawning the redis service.

Do you use env var in your tests? If not, it might be worth trying to change REDIS_PORT: 6380 to REDIS_PORT: 6379

I do, the relevant variables are REDIS_HOST and REDIS_PORT

I cannot change to port 6379, see my original post

I understand, i dont mean that you change the mapping, just the env var. In case that tests are hard codded to 6380

If I change the env variable, I would assume that my test would run in production since my production is running on 6379 on the same host which I want to avoid. docker inspect shows the mapping should be good. The logs of the spawned container shows that its running internally on 6379. Believe me if I say I tried hostname, localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, label name, container name with either 6379 and 6380. All with the same result. I'm stuck on this for about 2 weeks already. I am 1000% sure the issue has to do with how the runner spawns the redis service and the runners sandbox env.

My suspicions only grows because the issue only persists when the runner is running, outside I'm not able to reproduce this issue. To give a straight answer about your consern if the environment variables change, they do. They are not stuck on their default values.

Ok, another try — can you return the REDIS_HOST to  redistester and add to option --entrypoint redis-server before the others? If you want it to be 6380 internally as well, you can also --entrypoint redis-server -p 6380 but I don't think it matters.

It fails on the tests, not on the PING, right? If there's something's the runner do when it spawns without being config to, and there is, it might be worth it to specify exactly the entry command, redis-server and port.

If you can get from within the docker the details of the Redis service, it might help.

Yes, it only seem to fail with my test within the runner. I've added --entrypoint "redis-server" and --publish 6380:6379 before the ping. I also changed back REDIS_HOST to redistester. I had to remove --publish flag because it conflicts with the ports: section. Unfortunatly same connection issue after doing so. What would you like me to get from within the redis docker? I have to be fast because actions removes this container once the test fails.

redis-cli INFO output

I've included the output in a gist: https://gist.github.com/0x78f1935/2eba43ccba1188029bfee143561324a5

Unfortunately, everything looks good.

Yeah, I'm also lost.

Did you try not alpine?

A question - why not running inside debian image instead of self hosted, and use your setup regularly?

Because I don't want to worry about the minutes i've spend with the free github plan.
I've brought my own organization with 1 seat, so I can host those things myself.
Check here for more info! :)
The self-hosted image is based on an Debian image

I'm aware of self-hosted, our matrix of hosts is also included many self-hosted. But it seems that it's limiting you since you can't use the same naming and a clean env. But also on self-hosted — ill edit my answer with what I meant with some of our examples and maybe it will help.

Added, let me know

Thank you for updating your answer. Looking into the links you have provided, I notice that you don't use the key word services at all. You really are installing redis inside the steps. I also noticed this with the example @azeem provided. Looking back on the docs they specifically mention "The example uses the ubuntu-latest". There might be some misscomunication here, but you might be onto something. I need some time to validate this.

Yes, it is not what I do, just mentioning another tool you can utilize together to get more similar behaviors. My matrix run 5 different versions of ValKey/Redis-OSS, and running them inside a container has no value for our goal (we testing the client library, not the infra, we test what matter for it)

But generally speaking, I also wanted to mention it in the answer — if you test the real behavior of your app, don't use services, use it as you do in your up, just in a separate image inside the host. And if you just want Redis server, why all the hustle? Just run Redis locally. On top of that, using the container option I shared is good also because it leaves the env clean at the end of the run.

Small update; I'm thinking to refactor my current pipeline. But before I'm doing so, I wanted to re-produce the issue I have on another machine outside the runner's docker scope by using act. I've build an image that is basically a 1 on 1 clone of the runner. The command: act --pull=false --workflows .\.github\workflows\test_python_tests.yaml -P self-hosted=annihilator708/github-action-runner-act-clone:latest results in the same issue I had before. Time for a refactor.

Interesting! Which direction it's going?

I've got some good news, I finally been able to solve the issue (within act). Assuming it has been resolved inside the runner too (which I can't test right now until I add all my components back). I've dropped the whole services tag and am installing redis directly within my steps. My unittests finally succeed. Once I put everything together (working) I'll give you the bounty. I'll also update your answer once I get there. Thank you so much in advance!

I've updated your answer, I can confirm that it works now! Thank you!

Well, was a fun challenge :) although i appreciate the bounty, consideration of Glide will be a preferable prize. Good luck
